# CakePHP: Call controller::redirect from component

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to write a simple CakePHP component that will check a php session variable and redirect to a specific location if it is not set. This function is going to be used across multiple controllers and I just want to have the code for it one place (DRY and all).

The problem I am running into is that cake does not make `Controller` functions accessible to components so I cannot call `$this->redirect([routing array])`.

Is there a way around this? I would prefer not to add a return statement to the function that I then have to check in the controller, as that is all the function already does(a 1 line if statement) and seems like an unnecessary layer of abstraction. I am about to put the function in a seperate file outside of cake and just add  `include` into all of my controllers that need this function as a hacky way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check [Components API](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#component-api)

There you can see two callbacks

> Component::initialize(Controller $controller)
>
> The initialize method is called before the controller’s beforeFilter method.
>
> Component::startup(Controller $controller)
>
> The startup method is called after the controller’s beforeFilter method but before the controller executes the current action handler.

So, you can use  initialize(Controller $controller) or startup(Controller $controller) depend on your needs ( seems you need to use initialize )

in following way

```
    function initialize(Controller $controller ) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }
```

and later user in your code.  CakePHP send  current controller as value of $controller